# Cannot PATCH /api/v1/tasks POSTMAN and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

When I send a request using postman on that endpoint a 404 response comes and postman says that it Cannot PATCH /api/v1/tasks
here is my code

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const {getAllTasks, addTask, getSingleTask, updateTask, deleteTask} = require('../controllers');

// path => /api/v1/tasks
router.get('/tasks', getAllTasks);

// path => /api/v1/tasks
router.post('/tasks', addTask);

// path => /api/v1/tasks
router.get('/tasks/:id', getSingleTask);

// path => /api/v1/tasks
router.patch('/tasks/:id', updateTask);

// path => /api/v1/tasks
router.delete('/tasks/:id', deleteTask);

module.exports = router;
```

and in the server.js module

```
app.use('/api/v1', routes);
```

Comment: You don't have a handler for `PATCH /api/v1/tasks`. You do have one for `PATCH /api/v1/tasks/:id`. You would need to make a request like `PATCH http://localhost:xxxx/api/v1/tasks/some-task-id`

Comment: in POSTMAN => http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tasks?id=6202ddf2229ad24feff8a802

Comment: You're using query params where you have defined [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). Like I said, it should be `PATCH http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tasks/6202ddf2229ad24feff8a802`